# How to update and save the variable after it has been changed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, scope

I want to update the value of the counting variable after the words have been clicked, so they can be sorted from the highest clicked value from an array. 
The variable value doesn't carry over to the next button.

I made the two variables as global variables in order to use it in other functions, but it doesn't seem to work and I also want the submit button to get updates after the user clicks the words after they have submitted once.

```
<h4> Communication </h4>

  <button onclick="addressed()">addressed</button> , 
  <button onclick="arbitrated()">arbitrated</button> , 
<br>-------------------

   <p id="demo"> </p>
  <p id="demo1"> </p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Sort</button>

<p id="demo3"></p>


<script>

var countAddressed=0 ;
 var countArbitrated=0;

var mostChosen = [
 {word:"addressed:", selectedTimes:countAddressed},
  {word:"arbitrated:", selectedTimes:countArbitrated}];


//set every buttons for action words
function addressed() {

  countAddressed += 1;

  //count how many individual action words there are. 
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "addressed: " + countAddressed;

}

function arbitrated() {

  countArbitrated += 1;

  //count how many individual action words there are. 

 document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML ="arbitrated: " + countArbitrated;


}

function myFunction() {
 mostChosen.sort(function(a, b){return b.selectedTimes - a. selectedTimes});
 displayWords();
 }

 function displayWords() {
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML =
 mostChosen[0].word + " " +  mostChosen[0].selectedTimes + "<br>" +  mostChosen[1].word + " " +  mostChosen[1].selectedTimes + "<br>";
}
```

----I want this :

Communication

### addressed(button) ,  arbitrated (button),

addressed: 3

arbitrated: 5

Sort(button)
addressed: 5
arbitrated: 3

----but I am getting this:

Communication

### addressed ,  arbitrated ,

addressed: 3

arbitrated: 5

Sort
addressed: 0
arbitrated: 0

Comment: `mostChosen` is initialized with initial value and after that not changed. That's the reason you are seeing 0.

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the comment, you are not updating `mostChosen` array when buttons are clicked.

```
// Update addressed count in addressed() function
mostChosen.forEach(token => {
    if (token.word == 'addressed:') {
        token.selectedTimes = countAddressed;
    }
});
// Similar update is done in arbitrated() function
```

Here is the running code (your code, modified slightly) that modifies the array `mostChosen`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prescriptions</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h4> Communication </h4>

    <button onclick="addressed()">addressed</button> ,
    <button onclick="arbitrated()">arbitrated</button> ,
    <br>-------------------

    <p id="demo"> </p>
    <p id="demo1"> </p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Sort</button>

    <p id="demo3"></p>


    <script>

        var countAddressed = 0;
        var countArbitrated = 0;

        var mostChosen = [
            { word: "addressed:", selectedTimes: countAddressed },
            { word: "arbitrated:", selectedTimes: countArbitrated }];


        //set every buttons for action words
        function addressed() {

            countAddressed += 1;
            mostChosen.forEach(token => {
                if (token.word == 'addressed:') {
                    token.selectedTimes = countAddressed;
                }
            });

            //count how many individual action words there are. 
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "addressed: " + countAddressed;

        }

        function arbitrated() {

            countArbitrated += 1;
            mostChosen.forEach(token => {
                if (token.word == 'arbitrated:') {
                    token.selectedTimes = countArbitrated;
                }
            });
            //count how many individual action words there are. 

            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "arbitrated: " + countArbitrated;


        }

        function myFunction() {
            mostChosen = mostChosen.sort(function (a, b) { return b.selectedTimes - a.selectedTimes });
            displayWords();
        }

        function displayWords() {
            document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML =
                mostChosen[0].word + " " + mostChosen[0].selectedTimes + "<br>" + mostChosen[1].word + " " + mostChosen[1].selectedTimes + "<br>";
        }
    </script>

</body>
```